# Do the alert buttons not work in triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert

The alert works but the if statement for the ui.button.no wont work for some reason, this is all in an on selection change function by the way.

```
let sr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

    if(sr.getRange("S20").getValue()<=0){
      Logger.log('works')
    
      sr.getRange("V5").setValue(sr.getRange("V5").getValue()+1)
        var ui =SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
     ui.alert(
                                "You lose",
                                    "To play again click yes to stop click no. ",
                                      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
     
    if(ui.Button.NO){
      
        console.log('works')
        {
      var html = `
      <center><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*MqAtYx5e_k9S2M9sXTqEXQ.jpeg" /></center>
      <p class="title" style="font-family: sans-serif; color:white; text-align:center">
      Nice try!</p>
      `
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService
          .createHtmlOutput(html)
          .setWidth(1200)
          .setHeight(790);
          
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'In total you won: ' + sr.getRange('U5').getValue()+
      ' times and lost: ' + sr.getRange('V5').getValue());
            }   
    }
     }
```

Comment: sr is undefined. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

#### This works with onSelectionChange()

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`${JSON.stringify(e)}`,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(r == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    e.source.toast('OK');
  } else if (r == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {
    e.source.toast('Cancel');
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Hi, the first alert is working now but I still have a problem with the second HTML alert prompt.